# Remove weird looking orange PHP errors on Debian

Tags: php, debian-based

I set up a Debian virtual machine for local development, but funny enough any kind of PHP errors are displayed in an (too me) unusual design, with a orange table layout... How can I make PHP display errors the with the "traditional" design?

Update (added system explanation and screenshot): 
It's Debian running on a virtual machine on my Mac using VirtualBox.

[image]

Comment: It'd help if you post a screenshot of the "orange table layout" you're seeing.

Comment: @Nishant "... **Debian** virtual machine ...". Debian is Linux

Comment: @NishantSolanki he's talking about **Debian virtual machine**, where WAMP or XAMPP are not applicable

Comment: @preyz This sounds like Xdebug is enabled in your PHP config. Have a look through your configuration files for `extension=xdebug.so` and comment the respective lines out, or change `display_errors` to `Off`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring PHP on Debian and not about programming.

Comment: put `error_reporting(0)` on the top of your php page

Comment: Seems like this is not default Debian environment. Tell us more or ask it on serverfault.com (where you'll be asked for more info too)

Comment: @NishantSolanki Disabling error reporting completely is not the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment from Bojangles I investigated and found xdebug to be enabled. Disabling it removed the "orange" error output, and I now get "normal" error display.

I disabled it by removing the link to include the xdebug extension in /etc/php5/conf.d